# Masking 3d tensor using 2d mask numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I was trying to sove a very easy problem but due to my inexpericence with numpy I could not find a satisfying solution not requiring loops.

This is the proble:
I have 2 tensors like the following two:

```
data = np.random.rand(2,4,1000)
mask = np.array([[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0]])
```

Using the `mask`, I want to remove from `data` all the tensors that in the second dimension correspond to a 1. Therefore obtaining a data object with the shape:
`(2,3,1000)`
Assuming that all mask-arrays will always contain the same number of 1s (but on different positions), what is the easiest way of implementing this?

Comment: `data[~mask.astype(bool)].reshape(2, -1, 1000)`?